How to deploy Duende Identity Framework in an existing application
So far I only saw docs about deploying Duende IDP as a dedicated Application.
How can we deploy in an existing Application, so that:

ISSUER will be something like https://localhost:5001/idp
The UI will be generated under Pages/idp/...


Do you have a good reason for doing this?

Yeah, deployment fees. Deploying one app is cheaper than deploying two apps.

...what platform are you using? That certainly isn't the case in any of the major cloud providers I work with (e.g. Azure)

Maybe I am using Azure a wrong way, I am paying for each app separately.  Ok I got your point, but let's suppose that my concern makes sense, is it possible to do so? I mean deploy Duende IDP in an existing App

In Azure, you pay a flat rate for an App Service Plan, and you can host as many separate App Services in that plan for zero marginal cost - so yes, it does sound like you're using Azure wrong...

Ok, you killed it. I will follow the standard and use a dedicated app. Thanks
